# How can I convert a list to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, regex, list, dictionary

I want to convert this list:

```
 lst = ['Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitudeRef                 Ascii       2  East',
 'Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitude                    Rational    3  34deg 55\' 18.616" ',
 'Exif.GPSInfo.GPSAltitudeRef                  Byte        1  Above sea level',
 'Exif.GPSInfo.GPSAltitude                     Rational    1  151 m']
```

Into a dictionary :

```
a_dict = {'GPSLongitudeRef': 'East',
          'GPSLongitude': '34deg 55\' 18.616"',
          'GPSAltitudeRef': 'GPSAltitudeRef',
          'GPSAltitude': '151 m'}
```

I did try a regex expression:

```
tags = []
vals= []
for n in lst:
tags.append(re.findall('(?<=\w\.)(\w*)(?=\s)',n))
vals.append(re.findall('(?<=\d\s{2})(.*?)(?=\'\,)',n))
```

But although 'tags' are working, 'vals' comes out empty for some reason

Comment: at the end of any of your strings there are the characters `',`. Instead you could replace `(?=\'\,)` with `$` if you want to take the last token. In this way you do not even need the lazy quantifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one-liner that split lines by two whitespaces and uses dictionary comprehension.

```
result = {line.split("  ")[0] : line.split("  ")[-1] for line in lst}
```